# How do I click this button in System Preferences with applescript?

Tags: applescript

I am trying to use applescript to disable Siri, and I need to click the confirmation button.
Here is my code:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
activate
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.speech"
end tell
delay 0.5
tell application "System Events"
tell process "System Preferences"
    -- click checkbox "Enable Ask Siri" of window "Siri"

    if value of checkbox "Enable Ask Siri" of window "Siri" is 1 then
        click checkbox "Enable Ask Siri" of window "Siri"
    end if

    click button "Turn Off" of window "Dictation" of window "Siri"
end tell
end tell
```

The following line is the one that is not working

```
click button "Turn Off" of window "Dictation" of window "Siri"
```

[image: Siri Turn Off Button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *button* you're trying to click in on a *sheet*, e.g.:

**Change:**

```
click button "Turn Off" of window "Dictation" of window "Siri"
```

**To:**

```
click button "Turn Off" of sheet 1 of window "Siri"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!